# Use same codeigniter files session in second codeigniter from the first one which are having different database

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-session

I have two codeigniter projects working on `www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com/blog`. I want to use the same session generated in domain.com. Using the login of the first one. I tried having same sess_save_path for both the codeigniters but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: If you are using APIs to handle request. Try using JSON web token

ref: https://jwt.io/

Option 2: Use Local Storage for both Codeigniter

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

there are many different options available.

Comment: I want it to be done using codeigniter sessions only, As new session is getting set for the second application.I just want to stop that